# What opaque content exactly mean?

Tags: java, api, file

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#isRegularFile%28%29) we have the description of `isRegularFile()` method of the `BasicFileAttributes` interface:

> Tells whether the file is a regular file with opaque content.

What do they mean by "opaque content", not visible? and if so, does it mean that a file with transparent content is not a regular file?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means that under the hood, the API makes no effort to look inside the file to determine whether it really is a "regular file". A file can appear to be a regular file but might actually be encrypted, a virtual file system for some application, or any number of other things that Java doesn't know about. Java only relies on the directory entry or whatever other metadata about it is provided by the underlying operating system.

Comment: This provides some information and examples but I don't see how it relates back to the original question.  The API doesnt look inside files when you run `isRegularFile()`? or ever?  A file might be many things, but it's not stated which of those examples count as 'opaque'.

Comment: @user1445967 - I'm not sure I understand the comment. Of course one can (usually) look inside a file with Java (by opening and reading it). The point of the answer is that this particular method will decide whether a file is a "regular file" (as opposed to a directory, symbolic link, or other [e.g., `/dev/tt0` on Unix]) based only on information from outside the file itself. It's not that there is such a thing as a "file with opaque content", it's simply that this method doesn't use the file contents when deciding whether or not it is a regular file.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question better addresses the issue.  Namely, in some operating systems, physical hardware devices and also "special" devices can be addressed in the same way as files are.  In linux/unix, `/home/interestingDocument.txt` could be a file, but `/dev/hda` or `/dev/null` is usually a device and NOT a file.  Other things that do exist but are not files include things like links, etc.

[What is a "regular file" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547268/what-is-a-regular-file-in-java)