# Maven compile gives UnsupportedOperationException itself

Tags: java, maven, upgrade, java-17, openjdk-21

For idenditical maven jdk 21 project checkout. With the same versions of jdk and maven and while maven compiles on other's Windows 10 machine, maven compile on my Windows 10 machine with the same updates gives the following exception

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

        at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.ensureFile(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:87)
    
        at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:119)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager$ArchiveContainer.<init>(JavacFileManager.java:566)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.getContainer(JavacFileManager.java:329)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.pathsAndContainers(JavacFileManager.java:1078)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.indexPathsAndContainersByRelativeDirectory(JavacFileManager.java:1033)
    
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1228)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.pathsAndContainers(JavacFileManager.java:1021)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.list(JavacFileManager.java:777)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.DelegatingJavaFileManager.list(DelegatingJavaFileManager.java:83)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.list(ClassFinder.java:752)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.scanUserPaths(ClassFinder.java:696)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.fillIn(ClassFinder.java:570)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.complete(ClassFinder.java:311)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:682)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$PackageSymbol.members(Symbol.java:1178)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symtab.listPackageModules(Symtab.java:901)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.visitTopLevel(Enter.java:345)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:553)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:287)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:302)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:608)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:592)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:1072)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:947)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper(JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:136)
    
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:183)
    
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1140)
    
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:193)
    
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

Tried diffenent versions of maven and reinstalled jdk 21 and maven. And tried with different versions of maven compile plugin.  Intellij rebuild can compile the project with jdk 21, but maven compile fails. Maven compile either from Intellij or from a command prompt fails with the exception.  Maven has no problem with java 8.    But has the same problem with jdk17 and jdk21. Just on my machine.

Comment: Well, from that stack trace and [the source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/68b5aab020b8f3e001da54f21fbc0c6fd494932e/src/jdk.zipfs/share/classes/jdk/nio/zipfs/ZipFileSystemProvider.java#L87), it appears `javac` is trying to open a ZIP file (presumably a `*.jar` file) that is not a "regular file", and so the ZIP file system provider is throwing an exception. Perhaps it's a dependency cache problem; what happens if you clear the local Maven cache? If that doesn't help, then please provide a [mre].

Comment: @slaw that is perhaps the most unhelpful error I’ve seen in the JDK   “Regular file” is discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547268/what-is-a-regular-file-in-java

Comment: Thanks @slaw and Andersen. Being busy, have not got time to further try.  Actually it is related to java 8 to java 21 migration for spring boot projects / components.   To migrate to java 21 certain spring dependencies and some other dependencies need to upgrade. I did  clear the .m2/repository trying to get away with the issue.  I will try that strategy again.  For some dependencies, seemed what pulled by java 8 might not be accepted by java 21.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into that for some reason a path calculated by Maven is not considered a regular file by the JDK.   I have not seen this scenario before, but you can look into it yourself.

I let IntelliJ analyze the stack trace on a Maven project using OpenJDK 21, and found that the code throwing the exception looks like:

```
    private boolean ensureFile(Path path) {
        try {
            BasicFileAttributes attrs =
                Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
            if (!attrs.isRegularFile())
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So what you want to know is what value `path` has when the exception is thrown.  Since there is no logging at this location inside the JDK, the easiest is to run the Maven build in debug mode (or run `mvnDebug` from the command line and attach a debugger) with a breakpoint here and then inspect the variable when the breakpoint is hit.

It may be possible that it is immediately clear to you what the problem is when you see the value.  My *guess* would be either that your .m2/repositories folder in your home directory has been corrupted, or that it refers to a file or directory that does not exist in the file system.

Comment: Thanks Andersen.  Having been busy and will try mvnDebug

Comment: "_or that it refers to a file or directory that does not exist in the file system_" -- In that case, reading the attributes should throw an `IOException` and the method should simply return false. And I don't think it's a symbolic link issue either because `NOFOLLOW_LINKS` is not being passed. The `path` must actually point to a non-regular file, or the JDK is erroneously reporting the file to be non-regular. Not sure why either case would occur though.

Comment: @slaw this is on windows so things may have changed under the hood. Perhaps even in WSL or across file system borders.  Hopefully op will provide more details.